# Load a multidimensional array from 2 database queries and 2 loops

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am try to get a row of rep names as column headings and then under that heading the top ten sales items per that rep

I am try to get data to output like this:

RepName1 RepName2 RepName3 RepName4
(rep names come from Database and will never be a set number)

Underneath each rep name in the column their top ten selling items in descending order

Like so:

RepName1

(top selling info will be pulled from database)

1st selling item

2nd selling item

3rd selling item

4th selling item

5th selling item

6th selling item

7th selling item

8th selling item

9th selling item

10th selling item

Then start a new column with the next rep and his or her top ten sellers.

```
    $qry = "SELECT sales_rep_login FROM sales_reps WHERE status = 'A'";
    $return_reps = mysql_query($qry);
        $reps = array();
        while($repX = mysql_fetch_assoc($return_reps)) {
            $reps[] = $repX['sales_rep_login'];
        }

    foreach ($reps as $rep){
    $q="SELECT sales_quantity.style_num, sales_quantity.number_sold, sales_reps.fname, sales_reps.lname FROM catalog JOIN sales_quantity ON catalog.style_num = sales_quantity.style_num
        JOIN sales_reps ON sales_quantity.sales_rep_login = sales_reps.sales_rep_login
        WHERE catalog.status = 'A'
        AND catalog.season_id = '" . $_POST['season'] . "'
        AND sales_quantity.sales_rep_login = '" .$rep. "'
        AND sales_reps.status = 'A'
        ORDER BY sales_quantity.number_sold DESC LIMIT 10";
        $return_sales = mysql_query($q);
        $Total_Sales = array();
        while($Sales=mysql_fetch_assoc($return_sales)) 
        $Total_Sales[] = $Sales;
        } // end foreach
```

for some reason I am only getting the info for the very last rep.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a suggestion: I the project is easy to maintain, you really should migrate to PDO module instead, cause of mysql_* function are deprecated since php5.5 and remove from php7.0.

Comment: Step 1 is to stop using a deprecated API. Step 2 is to reduce those two queries to just 1. Then we can talk about display. For step 2, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Oh, and pretend it's `LIMIT 3` when addressing step 2.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting $total_Sales array. Define it before foreach.

```
$Total_Sales = array();  // define array here
foreach ($reps as $rep){
    $q="SELECT sales_quantity.style_num, sales_quantity.number_sold, sales_reps.fname, sales_reps.lname FROM catalog JOIN sales_quantity ON catalog.style_num = sales_quantity.style_num
        JOIN sales_reps ON sales_quantity.sales_rep_login = sales_reps.sales_rep_login
        WHERE catalog.status = 'A'
        AND catalog.season_id = '" . $_POST['season'] . "'
        AND sales_quantity.sales_rep_login = '" .$rep. "'
        AND sales_reps.status = 'A'
        ORDER BY sales_quantity.number_sold DESC LIMIT 10";
        $return_sales = mysql_query($q);

        while($Sales=mysql_fetch_assoc($return_sales)) 
        $Total_Sales[$rep][] = $Sales; // make 2 dimensional array
        }
```

Print $Total_Sales and see it it has all the values.

Use mysqli instead of mysql which is depreciated.

Considering the result array as

```
$Total_Sales = array
(
    'RepName1' => array(
            array('names' => '1st selling item','style' => 'DD39050BG','num' => '660'),
            array('names' => '2nd selling item','style' => 'DD39043','num' => '600'),
            array('names' => '3rd selling item','style' => 'DD79021','num' => '582')
        ),
    'RepName2' => array(
            array('names' => '1st selling item','style' => 'DD39050BG','num' => '660'),
            array('names' => '2nd selling item','style' => 'DD39043','num' => '600'),
            array('names' => '3rd selling item','style' => 'DD79021','num' => '582')
        ),

    'RepName3' => array(
            array('names' => '1st selling item','style' => 'DD39050BG','num' => '660'),
            array('names' => '2nd selling item','style' => 'DD39043','num' => '600'),
            array('names' => '3rd selling item','style' => 'DD79021','num' => '582')
        ),

);
```

Use the below code to display

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1 sold #ccc">
    <tr>
    <?php foreach($Total_Sales as $key=>$value){
        echo "<td>".$key;
        if(is_array($value) && count($value)>0){
            echo "<table>";
            foreach($value as $k=>$v){
                echo "<tr><td>".$v['names']."</td></tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I made the changes as suggested. Printed it and still have an empty array. should something go in the empty brackets.            $Total_Sales[$rep][] = $Sales;

Comment: It's deprecated. This fact may or may not have had a detrimental effect on its value.

Comment: So I have now changed to mysqli I am now getting the desired results in the array, but I need to know how to display it.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [names] => Steven Handmaker
            [style] => DD39050BG
            [num] => 660
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [names] => Steven Handmaker
            [style] => DD39043
            [num] => 600
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [names] => Steven Handmaker
            [style] => DD79021
            [num] => 582
        )
)
too much to display the whole thing the are 119 arrays

Comment: I am guessing 'Steven Handmaker' in the array is selling item. Am I correct?

Comment: Updated the answer. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: he is a rep. he would be in repname1